# Trying to add libxslt to Docker Container

Tags: php, docker, lamp

I've getting started with Docker, using the [LAMP repo](https://github.com/sprintcube/docker-compose-lamp) from GitHub as my starting point. I need to add the `libxslt` lib. I've tried adding this to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install libxslt-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-enable libxslt-dev
```

But keep getting error: `E: Unable to locate package libxslt-dev`

I've tried to search for the lib from the Docker container's command line `apt-cache search libxslt` but get no results.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to get this lib installed?

Thanks

---

Followed answer below (@vpalmerini) updating `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apt update && apt-get install -y libxslt-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-enable libxslt-dev
```

Which I thought was working:

```
Step 9/13 : RUN apt update && apt-get install -y libxslt-dev
```

[...]

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
libxslt1.1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libxslt1-dev libxslt1.1
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 756 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3001 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxslt1.1 amd64 1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1 [237 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libxslt1-dev amd64 1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1 [519 kB]
Fetched 756 kB in 0s (4903 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libxslt1.1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 21271 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxslt1.1_1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxslt1-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxslt1-dev_1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxslt1-dev:amd64 (1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1) ...
Setting up libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1) ...
Setting up libxslt1-dev:amd64 (1.1.32-2.2~deb10u1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Removing intermediate container b62504aca3f9
 ---> b62b7af34467
Step 10/13 : RUN docker-php-ext-enable libxslt-dev
 ---> Running in 181191c74fe5
error: 'libxslt-dev' does not exist
```

Also tried changing `RUN` command to match package found: `libxslt1-dev`

```
RUN docker-php-ext-enable libxslt1-dev
```

Still unable to enable `libxslt`

---

Further info, output from:

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

includes:

```
libxml2-dev:amd64               install
libxrender-dev:amd64            install
libxrender1:amd64               install
libxslt1-dev:amd64              install
libxslt1.1:amd64                install
libxt-dev:amd64                 install
```

But running `RUN docker-php-ext-enable libxslt1-dev` still gives

```
error: 'libxslt1-dev' does not exist
```

Comment: You've done the right approach, the problem is that the Linux distro of your base image doesn't have the package. What is the base image in you Dockerfile? Maybe the package has another name depending on the distro...

Comment: @vpalmerini Right I didn't think of that. Its using `FROM php:7.4.2-apache-buster`.

Comment: The good news it that is a Debian based one. I will post as an answer, ok?

Comment: You are confusing the **system development package** for `libxslt` (present on your distro with the specific name `libxslt1-dev`) which is required to install the **php extension** `xsl`. Here is a [oneliner self-trashable test](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/30c84ba7c4f477fec7e885738dd921c1) to show you the way.

Comment: @Zeitounator, That did the trick. Updated my Dockfile with `RUN apt update && apt install -y libxslt1-dev && docker-php-ext-install xsl`, XSL available. Thank you very much / diolch yn fawr

Comment: @Zeitounator I haven't accepted an answer to this yet. You're advice led to the answer so if you answer it below I will accept this as the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing the **php extension** called `xsl` with the **system development package** for `libxslt` (present on your base image Debian Linux distribution with the specific name `libxslt1-dev`) which is required to install that php extension.

Here is a basic Dockerfile to achieve your requirement. Note that, as a good practice, I made the install in a single run instruction with some extra cleanup at the end.

The `apt-get remove` line is optional but will reduce the layer size a bit more. Installing  `libxslt1-dev` and all its dependencies (`icu-devtools`, `libicu-dev`, `libicu63`, `libxml2`, `libxml2-dev`, `libxslt1.1`) is mandatory for installing the extension. But once it is done, the dev packages can be removed.

```
FROM php:7.4.2-apache-buster

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libxslt1-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install xsl && \
    apt-get remove -y libxslt1-dev icu-devtools libicu-dev libxml2-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing missing is that you have to update the packages of your image, then you will be able to install `libxslt-dev` package:

```
RUN apt update && apt-get install -y libxslt-dev
```

Comment: I was hopeful about this, alas:

Comment: I've just updated the question. It was looking good but can't seem to enable it `error: 'libxslt' does not exist` (have tried `libxslt`, `libxslt1-dev`)