# symfony/notifier + twig/inky-extra in dunglas/symfony-docker missing ext-xsl

Tags: php, docker, symfony

im ussing dunglas / symfony-docker  https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker

try add
https://symfony.com/doc/current/notifier.html

```
composer require symfony/twig-pack twig/cssinliner-extra twig/inky-extra
```

get error

```
srv/app # composer require symfony/twig-pack twig/cssinliner-extra twig/inky-extra
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/twig-pack twig/cssinliner-extra twig/inky-extra
Loading composer repositories with package information                                                                 Updating dependencies                                 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - twig/inky-extra[v2.13.0, ..., 2.x-dev, v3.0.4, ..., 3.x-dev] require lorenzo/pinky ^1.0.5 -> satisfiable by lorenzo/pinky[1.0.5, ..., 1.0.9].
    - twig/inky-extra[v2.12.0, ..., v2.12.5, v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., v3.0.3] require php ^7.1.3 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - lorenzo/pinky[1.0.5, ..., 1.0.9] require ext-xsl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xsl extension.
    - Root composer.json requires twig/inky-extra * -> satisfiable by twig/inky-extra[v2.12.0, ..., 2.x-dev, v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.x-dev].
```

try add apk add php-xls

```
/srv/app # apk add php8-xls
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  php8-xls (no such package):
    required by: world[php8-xls]
/srv/app # apk add php-xls
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  php-xls (no such package):
    required by: world[php-xls]
```

how i can install it ?

it work with

docker-php-ext-install xsl

Comment: The error is about `xsl` but you try to install `xls`?

Comment: Have a look at the `Dockerfile` of your project. If it looks like the "original" one from Kevin's repository, there should be examples about how to install additional extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's due to a typo, try to install the `libxslt-dev` dependency then install the `xsl` PHP extension:

```
docker run --rm -it php:8.2-fpm-alpine sh


/var/www/html # apk add --no-cache libxslt-dev
[…]
OK: 301 MiB in 72 packages

/var/www/html # docker-php-ext-install xsl
[…]

/var/www/html # php -m | grep xsl
xsl
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554220/trying-to-add-libxslt-to-docker-container/65669174#65669174) for further information.