Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "XSLTProcessor" not found
I have to work with a data base file data.xml and a stylesheet data.xsl for data.xml in docker. I put in a php file named fr.php this:
<?php

$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('data2.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('data2.xsl');

$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);?>

After I run the program, the web page for that php file show that: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "XSLTProcessor" not found in /var/www/html/fr.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/fr.php on line 11
I have enabled in php.in the extension for xsl and the result is same. I've looked for answers on stack overflow but they don't match, I'm working with xml in docker.

So what does phpinfo show for your XML/XSL extension(s)?

There are many with xml, but only one with xsl which have the authos. I done one if condition in php to say if xsl extension is enabled but not, the docker or i dont know what does not see the extension.

Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65669174/3710053
